# Регулярное выражение для вырезки тегов <br />

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Помогите, пожалуйста, вырезать все теги `<br />`, которые есть между bb-кодами [ul][/ul]

```
$text = preg_replace('/\[ul\]...\[\/ul\]/isu', '', $text);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, так:

```
$text = preg_replace_callback
(
    '|\[ul\](.*?)\[/ul\]|isu', // тут уж сами решайте как выцеплять
    function( $m )              // текст между [ul][/ul]
    {
        return preg_replace( '|<br\s*/?>|i', '', $m[0] );
    },
    $text
);
```

Comment: примерно на такое и надеялся :) Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Это проще и лучше сделать заменой строки. Воспользуйтесь функцией: [str_replace](http://www.php.su/str_replace)

```
<?php
// присваивает <body text='black'>
$bodytag = str_replace("%body%", "black", "<body text='%body%'>");

// присваивает: Hll Wrld f PHP
$vowels = array("a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U");
$onlyconsonants = str_replace($vowels, "", "Hello World of PHP");

// присваивает: You should eat pizza, beer, and ice cream every day
$phrase  = "You should eat fruits, vegetables, and fiber every day.";
$healthy = array("fruits", "vegetables", "fiber");
$yummy   = array("pizza", "beer", "ice cream");

$newphrase = str_replace($healthy, $yummy, $phrase);

// начиная с версии 5.0.0 доступен аргумент count
$str = str_replace("ll", "", "good golly miss molly!", $count);
echo $count; // 2
?>
```

Comment: Мне не нужен str_replace. Только через регулярное выражение.